# I want to zoom in on SEDE graphs

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

I can't see many details on some SEDE graphs. So I think it would be nice to be able to zoom in, maybe like how [rep graphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2016-12-06%2004:20:42Z) work.

Can we get zoom for SEDE graphs?

Comment: A quick inspection of the [source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/tree/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/flot) revealed that the [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/zooming/) library is used and that supports zooming. If Tim Stone doesn't answer or comment on this I'll experiment a bit to see if I can get this working so I can submit a PR.

Comment: @rene Tim Stone didn't answer or comment, and probably does not plan to do any of those.